# x2Go dependency requires unavailable nx packages on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos6, nx

I thought I'm at my wits ends trying to figure out how to resolve these dependencies...

```
[root@mrwizard yum.repos.d]# yum install x2goclient x2goserver
[...]
Error: Package: x2goclient-4.0.1.3-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: nxproxy
Error: Package: x2goagent-3.5.0.22-1.el6.i686 (epel)
           Requires: nxagent
```

Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dr2KEypK) with the full `yum install` output and my `repolist`.

I've investigated the installation on [x2go site](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver), I performed, in order, these steps to attempt the install:

1. Activate EPEL
2. And, I activated several other 'testing' repositories just in case.
3. Add the X2Go repo to your yum configuration (is this part of 'rhn-channel'?)
4. The [x2go announce list](https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/x2go-announcement/2014-January/thread.html) shows a current version on RHEL (4.0.1.13)--not by any means outdated.

Of course its all the more strange, because `nxagent 3.5` is already installed and working on my system! And the FAQ at x2go implies they should work together *"Nowadays the NX libs shipped with X2Go work as a replacement for the NXv3 that are not maintained by NoMachine anymore."*

Do you have CentOS or RedHat based server using x2Go? Can you explain what I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation instructions you linked to gave two separate and distinct installation methods, one involving EPEL and the other involving OBS. You seem to have done *both* of them, but they are mutually exclusive.

To resolve the problem, remove [the x2go repo file that you installed](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:redhat) and try again using only EPEL.

Comment: I tried the EPEL first, then added the x2go repo. I didn't know they were exclusive.

Comment: x2go repo works, `yum install x2goclient x2goserver`